# How to checksum an entire folder structure?

Tags: c#, filesystems, checksum

I have a large folder structure (i.e. 2-3GB worth of data) that needs to be verified against a separate structure on another drive.

Is there a way to checksum the entire directory structure to ensure that the two structures, as well as all file contents, match exactly?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool or for an algorithm?

Comment: Algorithm; some way to get a checksum string from two sets of folder trees.

Answer (score 0):

A checksum won't help you in this circumstance, as the same process is going to be reading both sets of data. A digest value like that is useful when you have to communicate across processes or systems (in other words, different "things" are reading the different targets) so that you can pass a smaller set of data across the communication channel.

In your case, your application is going to be reading both, so a simple comparison is going to be your best bet.